# when iframe page refreshes it redirect to the initial iframe page not to the current iframe page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

My website uses the iframe to load content inside div element. My problem is when a page is refresh it redirect to the initial iframe page not to the current iframe page.

Comment: Sounds like a frame is a poor choice of tool for whatever problem you are solving.

Answer (score 0):

an `iFrame` has a `src` tag with the url it displays, if the page that hosts the `iFrame` has refreshed then the `iFrame` will be rendered agin with it's initial values of course.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the `<iframe>` should always reset on reload of the page. That's a feature of them.

You will need to add a script that fires on load, views the URL and changes the `<iframe src="...">` accordingly.

However, if you want the browser navigation to persist you may be better off not using an `<iframe>` at all. What are you trying to load and why?

Comment: if some one use to browser's URL and hit enter key that time my iframe was redirect to main page not open with the current page.

Comment: @AmbalMani Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. If the user types in a URL and hits ENTER then their browser loads that page. Any `<iframe>` will honour the `src` attribute that it gets from the server. Any way around that behaviour (say user types in an URL, hits ENTER and gets a page in _your_ `<iframe>`) would be a huge security risk. Even IE blocks it.